# How is the damage done from the PSI - Rift ability calculated?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

The damage done from the Rift ability on the final mission seems hard to calculate, and seems based on will of the attacker and defender.

**Does anyone have a good calculation for this yet?**

I've noticed:

- 15 Damage on Muton Elite
- 10(?) Damage on Ethereal.
- 8 Damage on Uber Ethereal.
- 4 Damage on Stim'ed assault soldier with 150+ willpower  (I sent her in for the kill!)

Comment: Oddly enough, for a psi power, it seems to have high damage against robotic enemies. I guess it counts them as having very low will rather than as being immune.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean Rift ability? It is only one that seems to match your description.

Anyway, the damage is calculated by taking the casters Will score and the targets Will score and deducing targets score from casters and using remainder to see how much damage is done.

Unless my own studies are wrong, it deals base damage of 4 and then additional +1 for every 5 Will left after deducting victims Will from users Will.

This means, that targets with low Will (such as Mutons and especially robotics) suffer a lot, but units with very high will will suffer less.

As such, for example, if the caster has 100 will and opponent has 80, then when the rift hits it's going to do 4 + (100-80)/5 = 4 + 20/5 = 4 + 4 = 8 damage.

tl;dr

Less Will the target has, more damage it takes.

I try to see if I can find the exact math from the game files, but I doubt it. If anyone has the exact formula, feel free to say it.

Comment: Yes.  I meant Rift.  TY.  Question was edited to keep the Starcraft Googlers away.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research.

Rift's damage depends on both attacker's and victim's will.
On classic difficulty ethereal has 145 will.
Damage dealt by ethereal's rift seems to be like this:
Rift damage = 6 + (145-X)/10(rounded down) (+2 against humans) (-3 against mind shield) (-2 against psi armor),
where 'X' is victim's will (including buffs).
Rift damage can't get lower than 4.

Thus, ethereal's rift deals:
6 damage to ethereal, 
20 damage to robotic units (0 will), 
18 damage to elite muton (20 will), 
9 damage to sectoid commander (115 will), 
5 damage to my support (114 base will + mind shield), 
5 damage to my squaddie (174 will because of "lead by example" effect), 
7 damage to my MEC (110+20 will). 
(It`s all tested)

You may buff/debuff the ethereal to get stronger/weaker rift.
If you use psi inspiration on ethereal, the rift deals 23 damage to mechtoid instead of 20.
If you use mindfray 3 times, than rift deals 11 damage to elite muton instead of 18.

But my formula isn`t accurate:
rookie (40 will + mind shield) should get 12 damage but he gets 11, 
squaddie (50 will) should get 17 damage but he gets 16, 
sniper (111 will) should get 11 damage but he gets 10 
etc

So you can calculate damage approximately.
Just use your soldier`s will instead of '145', it works the same way.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this you can [edit] in?